# jQuery in Chrome returns "block" instead of "inline"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have two divs that are inline. they both have similar styles and importantly both are inline.

JQuery is reporting that their css "display" is block ONLY in chrome.  I really need to know that these two are inline.

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MKRac/)

css:

```
div
{
    display: inline;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.div1
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid grey;
}

.div2
{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="div1">1</div>
<div class="div2">2</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery("div").click(function()
{
    jQuery(this).append("<br/><span>" + jQuery(this).css("display") + "</span>");
});

jQuery("div").click();
```

Does anyone know what is happening or more importantly what can I do? *(other than pull my hair out... its starting to hurt ;) )*

Comment: Are you aware that `float: left` forces `display: block`? `display: inline` isn't doing anything. Remove it if you don't believe me.

Comment: Doh! put it in an answer and i'll mark it correct. Also where would i find this information? w3c?

Comment: Yes, [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo). (Edit: Sorry, didn't update to see the answer posted below containing the exact same link :( )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I said in my comment, `float: left` forces `display: block`.

Here's the relevant information in the spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-float

> The element generates a **block box** that
>   is floated to the left.

And then:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

> Otherwise, if 'float' has a value
>   other than 'none', the box is floated
>   and 'display' is set according to the
>   table below.

To summarize said table: `float` = `display: block`.

Comment: thanks. Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MKRac/1/ incase anyone else has the same issue/