# CSS Menu underneath other divs

Tags: jquery, css

in IE7 and IE8 my menu is showing up underneath the slideshow div that is below it (when you hover over one of the menu options)

http://www.christmastreesandlights.co.uk

It works as expected in Chrome, FF and IE9.

Anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You may be interested in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156192/internet-explorer-z-index-bug

Comment: I don't have to look at your website I am guessing its the display:inline; that has that problem but I will double check lol

Comment: For some reason, you have this: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">` - that forces IE into IE7 mode. Your menu *would* work fine in IE8 without that silly meta tag. Although, it is still broken in IE7, so your question is still valid.

Comment: Yep I was right on ur `<li>` tag change `display:inline;` to  `display: block;` they do float left anyways so no need for inline :)

Comment: @Val: That's just not it, not by a long shot. [`float: left` forces `display: block`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854463/jquery-in-chrome-returns-block-instead-of-inline/5854523#5854523). So, `display: inline` isn't doing anything, except possibly working around [an IE6 bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/floatIndent.html).

Comment: I'd love to argue with you, but if i.e. wasnt so buggy, he wudnt have this problem, I have had that problem b4, n display inline was where I found the problem was simple as.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. Its frustrating, as I havnt done the coding for the menu ive just been told to use it and it has about 8 css stylesheets being called in the head. @thirtydot, ive tried what Val said and it doesnt alter anything :confused:

Comment: @Val: You're right that the problem is because of an IE bug. Let's just leave it there :) @Wayners247: It *is* the problem posted in the first comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156192/internet-explorer-z-index-bug I'm looking at the specifics of how to fix your page at the moment.

Comment: Hi, have you tried sorting this out using z-index values (menu z-index > slideshow z-index)? Just don't forget to specify position for each element.

Comment: @thirtydot, thanks for your help. Z-Index has worked for me, still needs tweaking. Its all 'inside' a Netsuite webstore which is simply horrible!! Thanks for everyones help with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related with z-index, but not with the z-index of the hovered state div; but with the z-index of the parent div.

This is something that happens only with internet explorer. To make this work correctly you need to declare the z-index of the parent.

You can view more about this issue in this excellent article: http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index. Apply a higher z-index to the menu container than the other divs of the same depth.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `z-index: 999;`