# How to create click-able CSS sprite with <a> rather than Javascript?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-sprites

Here is an example of click-able CSS sprite implemented with Javascript:

[Live demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/t629m/)

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(http://perfectwebtutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/spritecss.png);
    background-position: -300px -100px;
}
div:hover {
    background-position: -100px -100px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('div').click(function() {
        window.location = "http://google.com";
    });
});
```

Is that possible to achieve the same **without Javascript** ?

(The only way I can think of is to use `<a href="...">`, but how ?)

Comment: Yes. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/t629m/9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an `<a>` element, give it a `href` and `display: inline-block`, along with all the other CSS properties you have set.

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(http://perfectwebtutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/spritecss.png);
    background-position: -300px -100px;
}
a:hover {
    background-position: -100px -100px;
}
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t629m/13/**

Answer (score 4):

You asked your question in a convoluted way, but the answer is simple:

- Change the `div` to an `a`.
- Apply `display: block` to the `a`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/65HdK/

```
<a href="http://google.com/"></a>

a{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(http://perfectwebtutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/spritecss.png);
    background-position: -300px -100px;

    display: block
}
a:hover {
    background-position: -100px -100px;
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, if you want to have multiple instances of this next to each other, you either need [`display: inline-block`](http://jsfiddle.net/t629m/14/) (as in @Andy E's answer), or you can use `float: left`. If you use `float: left`, [you can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854463/jquery-in-chrome-returns-block-instead-of-inline/5854523#5854523) leave out `display: block`: [http://jsfiddle.net/65HdK/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/65HdK/1/).

Answer (score 2):

@misha,check the like http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/t629m/7/

the main thing is that you have to `display:block` in `<a>` tag

because `<a>` is an `inline element` 
example:

```
a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(http://perfectwebtutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/spritecss.png);
    background-position: -300px -100px;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://google.com"><div></div></a>
```

Seems to be working fine. Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vuZz4/

Comment: This is only valid for HTML5, which may or may not be a problem for the OP.

Comment: Well, I think that it would be a better solution to use a-tag instead then. I just wrote the first thing that came to my mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply change it a `<a>` and add display:block or similar to your css.

Example here.

http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/t629m/11/