# IE Compatibility issue: <span> inside <h2>

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have the following HTML/CSS, which simply has a `<span>` tag styled with `float:right` inside an `<h2>` tag:

```
<style>h2{background-color:#e2e2e2;}
span{float:right;border:1px solid red;}</style>
<h2>H2 Test <span>SPAN text</span></h2>
```

Everything works well on Firefox (and I suspect other good browsers, like Chrome, Opera, etc.), but in IE, the `<span>` gets forced to the next line.

Note: the image shows an example of Firefox and IE. [image]

How can I get IE to duplicate the behavior of Firefox?

Additional info: I am not locked into using `float:right`, all I really want is a portion of the text left aligned, and a portion of the text right aligned within the `<h2>`. I have tried numerous things, but IE always seems to be the browser that just won't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I could be wrong which is why this is being posted as a comment rather than an answer.  But don't you typically only apply "float" to block level elements?  Span is not a block, but an in-line element and perhaps that's why IE is not playing nice with it.

Comment: Same thing happens with a `<div>` tag. I thought perhaps a `<span>` may not wrap like that because it is not a block level element.

Comment: This works, but i'm not sure it's quite the behavior you want. Lemme know and i'll try and change it if it's not: http://jsfiddle.net/DctfL/12/

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing with? Which versions of IE do you care about? Could you add the complete HTML you're using for that "H2 Test" image?

Comment: I'm reading more about this now and the consensus I'm finding so far is that you can't apply "float" to non-block level elements.

Comment: @Sparky672: That's simply not true. [`float` forces `display: block`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854463/jquery-in-chrome-returns-block-instead-of-inline/5854523#5854523).

Comment: @thirtydot: I am happy with IE8+. The entire code is posted (I wasn't worried about adhearing to the standards for a simple example).

Comment: @Sparky672: You are getting too hung up on `float:left`, that was just a simple demo. It even says in the question: "I am not locked into using `float:left`"

Comment: @steveo225: So you're telling me that your three line snippet of code is your **ENTIRE** file? If that's the case, I know the answer here.

Comment: @thirtydot:  Reading lots of variation in opinion on this. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @steveo225:  I'm not hung up on anything.  I was just trying to ascertain whether "float" is valid on inline elements or not.

Comment: @thirtydot: This is not where the final solution is going, but I made the image from only the code specified. If I can get IE to behave nicely with this small example, I can roll it in without problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

html:

```
<h2><span class="_1">H2 Test</span><span class="_2">SPAN text</span></h2>
```

css:

```
h2{background-color:#e2e2e2;overflow:hidden}
span._1{float:left}
span._2{float:right;border:1px solid red;}
```

jsfiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/shmZR/