# CSS Floating inline elements (960 GS)

Tags: css, 960.gs

I was just checking out 906.gs css code and noticed that they made all the floated divs inline.

http://960.gs/demo.html

Just wondering what the purpose of that is...I am always interested in learning CSS theories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An element with `float: left` is forced to have a computed `display` value of `block`.

For more information on that, see: [jQuery in Chrome returns "block" instead of "inline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854463/jquery-in-chrome-returns-block-instead-of-inline/5854523#5854523)

The purpose of also adding `display: inline` is to fix an **IE6 bug**, the "double margin bug":

http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html

> A coder innocently places a left float
>   into a container box, and uses a left
>   margin on the float to push it away
>   from the left side of the container.
>   Seems pretty simple, right? Well it is
>   until it's viewed in IE6. In that
>   browser the left float margin has
>   mysteriously been doubled in length!

It's a free fix with *no downsides* (even in IE6):

> That means that {display: inline;} on
>   a float should be no different than
>   using {display: block;} (or no display
>   value at all), and indeed all browsers
>   follow this specification, including
>   IE. But, this does somehow trigger IE
>   to stop doubling the float's margin.
>   Thus, this fix can be applied
>   straight, without any fussy hiding
>   methods.
>
> In fact, you could just apply the
>   Inline Fix to all floats if you like,
>   since there are no known side-effects.
>   That way the bug can never gain
>   traction regardless of any margins you
>   might or might not use.