# Redundant CSS rules ie float & display:block

Tags: css

I just found out that floating an element will also make it a block, therefore specifying a float property and **display:block** is redundant.

(What would happen if you tried to specify **display:inline** and **float:left**? )

Are there any other examples of redundant combinations to watch out for? block & width ? etc,

Is there a tool that can check for such things?

Comment: I don't know what you mean "redundant request for 'other examples" and "a tool to check for such things'"

Comment: @thirtydot: I think you mis-read the Question > given "float:left; display:block;" the "display:block" is redundant, no? I wondered what other combinations might be redundant. "display: roflcopter; float: top" is your best example?

Comment: I'm going to write a better answer to replace the comments I'm about to remove.

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float - "As float implies the use of the block layout, it modifies the computed value of the display values in some cases:"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I just found out that floating an
>   element will also make it a block,
>   therefore specifying a `float` property
>   and `display:block` is redundant.

Yes, `display: block` is redundant if you've specified `float: left` (or `right`).

> (What would happen if you tried to
>   specify display:inline and float:left?
>   )

`display: inline` will not make any difference, because setting `float: left` forces `display: block` "no matter what":

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

> Otherwise, if 'float' has a value
>   other than 'none', the box is floated
>   and 'display' is set according to the
>   table below.

To summarize said table: `float` = `display: block`.

However, your specific example of `float: left; display: inline` *is useful* in one way - [it fixes an IE6 bug.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351119/css-floating-inline-elements-960-gs/6351155#6351155)

> Are there any other examples of
>   redundant combinations to watch out
>   for? block & width ? etc,

Some examples:

- If you set `position: absolute`, then `float: none` is forced.
- The `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` properties will not have any effect unless `position` has been set to a value other than the default of `static`.

> Is there a tool that can check for
>   such things?

I don't *think* so. It's not something that is ever needed, so I can't see why anybody would have written such a tool.

Comment: Thanks for the examples, exactly what i was looking for. Just as an example, a quick look thru Stack Overflow's css shows many classes which specify float:left and display:block - you don't think that it's good practise to remove unnecessary stuff from css files, and that a tool for this could be helpful?

Comment: It's not really a *problem* per se, because CSS files are often hundreds if not thousands of lines long, and removing a single  property isn't going to make any noticeable difference. But yes, I'd agree that it's good practise to leave it out because it's unnecessary. After all, "perfection is achieved when there is nothing left to take away".

Answer (score 1):

From my experience IE6 has problems with float:left. For compatibility, display:inline is added with floating statements.