# Clearing inputs without adding Float

Tags: html, css, input, css-float

Submit buttons don't seem to clear properly without also adding float. Can someone clear this up for me (no pun intended).

http://jsfiddle.net/qb5TH/

CSS:

```
.left {float:left}
.clear {clear:both}
```

Form:

```
<form>
  <label class="left">Label</label>
  <input type="text" class="left">
  <label class="clear left">Label</label>
  <input type="text" class="left">
  <input type="submit" class="clear">
</form>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, see how second case the submit button goes to next line. http://jsfiddle.net/qb5TH/1/

Comment: It's not submit buttons, it's inline elements.  Try with a span, same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I might not be exactly clear on your intent but if you want to get your button to it's own line you can force it to use display: block and it will go to the next line.

Here's the CSS:

```
.left {float:left;}
.clear {clear:both;}
input[type=submit] {display: block;}
```

**[jsfiddle sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/msisson/gFaLT/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the submit button doesn't move to the next line is because `input` is an *inline* element. According to the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control), `clear` is ignored on inline elements (relevant quote: "Applies to: block-level elements").  Setting `float` on the submit button works because [setting `float` in most cases also sets `display: block`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372021/redundant-css-rules-ie-float-displayblock).  You can achieve the same effect by directly setting `display: block` on the submit buttons that you want to clear:

```
.left {float:left}
.clear {clear:both}
input[type=submit].clear {display:block}
```