# How do I align a <label> with a <span> when the <span> sometimes goes onto multiple lines?

Tags: html, css

My code is:

```
<label>Something:</label> <span>Some Value</span>
<br/>

<label>Something:</label> <span>Some Value</span>
<br/>
```

The `<label>` has a fixed width.

Output:

```
Something:  Some Value
Something:  Some Value
```

However if Some Value is quite long it wraps incorrectly

```
Something:  Some Value
Something:  Some Value Some
Value Some
```

Is there a nice solution to this so it lines up as you'd expect? I'm making rather a large table of data and it's not possible to predict which values will span multiple lines in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can fix the width of both elements apply `display:block` and `float:left`.  This will create a column like appearance and cause the span to wrap within the column.

**CSS**:

```
   label, span{
        float: left;
        width: 150px; /* Adjust widths to fit your needs */
    }

   br{ clear: both;}
```

**HTML**

```
<label>Something:</label> <span>Some Value</span>
<br/>

<label>Something:</label> <span>Some Value that is alot longer and wraps</span>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gvPdQ/

Comment: You don't need to use `display:block` and `float:left` both. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/gvPdQ/1/)

Comment: @tewathia Interesting, it appears that when you float the element the browser automatically applies `display:block`.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/gvPdQ/2/  Do you know if this occurs cross browser?

Comment: @KevinBowersox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372021/redundant-css-rules-ie-float-displayblock

Comment: @SLC For multiple rows you can wrap the `span` and `label` tags.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/hx27k/1/ or you can add `clear:both` to the `br` tags: http://jsfiddle.net/hx27k/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to tweak you markup I have the following solution. Requires that labels are fixed width; the spans fill remaining space.

### HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <label>Something:</label> <span>Some Value</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label>Something:</label> <span>Some Value Some Value Some Value Some Value Some Value Some Value Some Value Some Value Some Value Some Value</span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.row {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.row label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
.row span {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 210px; /* equal to label width plus some gap */
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/RZJ2v/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are making “a large table of data”, use a `table` element, e.g.

```
<table>
<tr><th>Something <td>Some value
<tr><th>Something <td>Some value
...
</table>
```

You can still set a fixed width on Something, but you need not.

It is incorrect to use the `label` element for anything else than labelling a labellable element (normally, a control, i.e. form field).