# How would I make these two elements on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I have a [fiddle, that while basic to some](http://jsfiddle.net/sLj65/1/) is not very to me, The two elements in the fiddle are in their own div (and span), as they should be - they each have a `display: block` and their `text-align` is either left or right based on where they should be in the containing element. The issue I cannot seem to figure out with out doing some kind of hacky css, like `position relative;` and `top: 10px` (roughly) - **is how to make them on the same line**  That is `.text-one` and `.text-two` should be on the same line, both "aligned" to their side of the element. I could do it all in one div, but I want them in separate "containers" as you see them.

Thoughts? I believe this is rather simple, but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Please include some code in your post so we can better assist you.

Comment: change your text-aligns to float as in this fiddle .. http://jsfiddle.net/sLj65/3/

Comment: @Obsidion no theres a link to the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by simply floating the elements.

### CSS

```
.box{
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 14px 27px 10px 15px;
    min-height: 60px;
    min-width: 60px;
}

.box .text-one{
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    float:left;
}

.box .text-two{
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sLj65/7/

Answer (score 2):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/sLj65/4/)**

Either use `inline-block` along with `width` of 50% or better use `float:left` on `.text-one` if you want to use `display:block`

Answer (score 1):

### http://jsfiddle.net/sLj65/6/

```
.box .text-one{
    float:left;
    text-align: left;
}

.box .text-two{
    float:right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

`display:block;` means they will not appear on the same line if a float is not set, to do this you must float them to either side. I would also add `max-width:50%;`to each `.box` element if you plan on adding more text to each element.

Comment: Your last comment, that as `block` displayed elements are not shown on one line is not totally true actually. They will, if they are floated, but by default they have a width of 100%. So `display: block` together with a `width` (or `max-width`) will do the trick

Comment: that's what i meant without the float!

Comment: "to do this you must float them" by adding float `display:block;` is made redundant and is made the default, so it's pointless keeping it!

Comment: not true either ;) displaying a span as a block element gives you a different result, as a span is normally `inline`, meaning any width and height will be ignored. This isn't necessarily important in this case, but if you give an answer, you should be precise and correct IMO

Comment: I said when floated the default is made block.... not that the default of span is block :D

Comment: yup, I understood. So I said adding display:block is _not_ redundant ;)

Comment: if it's set then it's made redundant if display inline is set then it's changed, are your being purposefully difficult!! http://stackoverflow.com/a/6373639/1742280

Comment: Aaaah, you're totally right! (as I didn't realize `inline` will convert to `block` automatically when floating). And with your addition in your last edit ("if a float is not set") you corrected the  possible confusion on which I remarked in my first comment. You just earned yourself a +1 ;) (and no, I was not bugging you purposefully ;))

Comment: Sorry my bad, I changed it as to not confuse any one else :)