# Difference Between 'display: block; float: left' vs. 'display: inline-block; float: left'?

Tags: html, css-float, block, css

Is there a practical difference between whether a left-floated element (say, and image) has display: inline-block; applied to it, as opposed to leaving the default display: block; rule applied?

In other words, what's the difference between:

```
<div style="float: left; display: inline-block;">text</div>
```

and

```
<div style="float: left; display: block;">text</div>
```

?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: Don't you know the difference between inline-block and block? For example... a DIV is a block level element, SPAN is an inline element. You're like asking what's the difference between block element and inline element which is self-explanatory.

Comment: To be honest the only difference I can think of is the usage of vertical-align with floated elements. When you use block, there is no vertical align, with inline-block there is. Especially when You are floating multiple elements one by another.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An answer by @thirtydot might help you... [Question's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372021/redundant-css-rules-ie-float-displayblock/6373639#6373639)

> I just found out that floating an
>   element will also make it a block,
>   therefore specifying a `float` property
>   and `display:block` is redundant.

Yes, `display: block` is redundant if you've specified `float: left` (or `right`).

> (What would happen if you tried to
>   specify display:inline and float:left?
>   )

`display: inline` will not make any difference, because setting `float: left` forces `display: block` "no matter what":

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

> Otherwise, if 'float' has a value
>   other than 'none', the box is floated
>   and 'display' is set according to the
>   table below.

To summarize said table: `float` = `display: block`.

However, your specific example of `float: left; display: inline` *is useful* in one way - [it fixes an IE6 bug.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351119/css-floating-inline-elements-960-gs/6351155#6351155)

> Are there any other examples of
>   redundant combinations to watch out
>   for? block & width ? etc,

Some examples:

- If you set `position: absolute`, then `float: none` is forced.
- The `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` properties will not have any effect unless `position` has been set to a value other than the default of `static`.

> Is there a tool that can check for
>   such things?

I don't *think* so. It's not something that is ever needed, so I can't see why anybody would have written such a tool.

Comment: What about inline-block with vertical align, and multi floats? Isn't vertical align property an additional difference?

Comment: @JacekKowalewski, no, `vertical-align` works only for inlines, inline-blocks, and various table elements.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to specify a `float: left` and a `display: inline-block` for the same element, you use one or the other, not both. Float is used to float text around elements, its not the best weapon to choose when doing a layout. Go with display: block, and inline-block.

http://joshnh.com/2012/02/07/why-you-should-use-inline-block-when-positioning-elements/

**Block elements** — form boxes according to the css box-model. They have width, height, padding, border, and margin and they stack vertically on top of each other.

**Inline elements** — don’t form boxes. They sit horizontally next to each other.

**Inline-block elements** — act like block elements on the inside where they form boxes. On the outside they act like inline elements sitting horizontally next to each other instead of stacking on top of each other.

A good resource: http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html

According to SitePoint:

> If you’re new to CSS layouts, you’d be forgiven for thinking that
>   using CSS floats in imaginative ways is the height of skill. If you
>   have consumed as many CSS layout tutorials as you can find, you might
>   suppose that mastering floats is a rite of passage. You’ll be dazzled
>   by the ingenuity, astounded by the complexity, and you’ll gain a sense
>   of achievement when you finally understand how floats work.
>
> Don’t be fooled. You’re being brainwashed.

http://www.sitepoint.com/give-floats-the-flick-in-css-layouts/

Answer (score 2):

When you use `float: left;` almost any elements behave as a `block` element. So there is no any difference in this particular case.

[image]

Comment: @Vishal, I've said that when you use `float: left;` or `float: right;` any element becomes a block element. Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh! Right @seva.rubbo there was a misunderstanding though... sorry :)