# Two div on the same line

Tags: html, css

Why are these two lines "First text" and "Second text" **not** on the same line?

```
<html>
    <body style="width: 20px;">
        <div style="width: auto; display: block; white-space: nowrap;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; float: left;">First text</div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; float: left;">Second text</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are floating the element.

Remove the `float: left;`, or make it `display: block;`

See also: [Difference Between 'display: block; float: left' vs. 'display: inline-block; float: left'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511533/difference-between-display-block-float-left-vs-display-inline-block-flo)

```html
<html>
    <body style="width: 20px;">
        <div style="width: auto; display: block; white-space: nowrap;">
            <div style="display: inline-block;">First text</div>
            <div style="display: inline-block;">Second text</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`float: left` cancels out the `display: inline`

```html
<html>
    <body style="width: 20px;">
        <div style="width: auto; display: block; white-space: nowrap;">
            <div style="display: inline-block;">First text</div>
            <div style="display: inline-block;">Second text</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `float:none` with `display: inline-block`