# Float can't be used with display:inline-block issue

Tags: css, css-float

I wrote the following CSS in WordPress:

```css
.post-source {
  color: #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  float: left;
}
```

And then I received a warning:

> float can't be used with display:inline-block issue

Currently the code works with no issue. But I want to know is there anyway I can improve this code better to avoid potential issue.

Thank you!

Comment: The message says that float will be ignored du to display set to inline. Use either of it

Comment: @Vega it's the opposite, when using float the inline-block will be useless because the computed value of display will be *forced* to block : https://stackoverflow.com/q/27511533/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif, oops, you are right :)