# Layout problem (floats) specific to Opera

Tags: css, css-float, opera

I have a forum title bar (with forum name and thread title). Forum name, when long, is clipped and revealed on `:hover`. The objective is to have the thread title to begin next to forum name, hovered or not, and also clipped, when too long.

The following [reduced test case](http://jsfiddle.net/wkA7q/3/) works in Chrome and FF but not in Opera (tested on 11.50 alpha, and latest stable, both on mac).

**Correct behaviour:** thread title (the one with red outline) is in line with forum name.

**What I get in Opera:** the text is gone - actually hidden by `overflow:hidden` on `.nav_bar`, it gets moved to next line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`display: inline-block; float: left` is not logical because [`float: left` forces `display: block`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854463/jquery-in-chrome-returns-block-instead-of-inline/5854523#5854523).

Due to your use of `white-space: nowrap`, I'm going to keep `display: inline-block` and drop `float: left`.

That gets us to here: http://jsfiddle.net/wkA7q/4/

It's now consistently visible, but the text is not aligned in most browsers.

To fix that, add `vertical-align: top` a couple of times: http://jsfiddle.net/wkA7q/5/

That works and is consistent between Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE9/8.

*(I realise that I'm not really addressing the reason why Opera displays differently here. Although `display: inline-block; float: left` do conflict with each other, the outcome is well defined.)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. That issue caused me lots of frustration.