# Calculated style forced into something else

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with the following css properties set via its `class`:

- display: inline-block
- float: left
- clear: none

But when I see that object on Chrome tool "Computed Style" area, `display: inline-block` is recognized but is crossed out, and is calculated as "display: block". Why is this happening?

The class name for this `<div>` is called `hbox_elem`, and the computed style appears like this:

[image: computed style]

I tried Evan's suggestion, and now I get this, but it still does not work:

[image: computed style2]

Comment: I just remembered, I've answered this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854463/jquery-in-chrome-returns-block-instead-of-inline/5854523#5854523

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`float: left` forces `display: block` for most values of `display`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

> Otherwise, if 'float' has a value other than 'none', the box is floated and 'display' is set according to the table below.

An extract of the table:

```
Specified value | Computed value  
--------------------------------
inline-block    | block
```

Comment: Thanks for pinpointed information. That is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Another CSS rule may be overriding it. Try placing `!important` after `inline-block` to verify.

```
div.hbox_elem
{
    display:inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: Is there a certain property that is making this overriden?

Comment: Do you have/can you post a live example somewhere? (JSFiddle, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, I had it screwed up somewhere, and now I found what was wrong. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @thirtydot: Even I agree with you.

Comment: @thirtydot I thought my problem was solved, so I just accepted it so that this question will not remain in the unanswered section. Now that thirtydot gave another answer, I will accept that.